# How can I refactor this rails code in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I currently have this inside my controller:

```
        @employees = Employee.all
        #need to keep params different because of nested route(id) and filter form params
        if !params[:employee].blank? && !params[:contact].blank?
            @logs = Log.both_filters(params[:employee], params[:contact]).date_ordered
        elsif params[:employee_id] 
            @logs = Log.by_employee(params[:employee_id]).date_ordered
        elsif !params[:employee].blank?
            @logs = Log.by_employee(params[:employee]).date_ordered
        elsif params[:contact_id]
            @logs = Log.by_contact(params[:contact_id]).date_ordered
        elsif !params[:contact].blank?
            @logs = Log.by_contact(params[:contact]).date_ordered
        else
            @logs = Log.all.date_ordered
        end
    end
```

I had to set two different params because the index is also a nested route for employees and for contacts (params[:contact_id]) and then I also wanted to distinguish loading from a two filters (params[:contact]).

I set the params for the filters in my model:

```
        where(employee: employee_id)
    end 


    def self.by_contact(contact_id)
        where(contact: contact_id)
    end
```

It just looks like a lot of logic in my controller and there's minor repetition. Im only on Ruby on Rails, no JS yet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate class to handle that:

```
class LogFilter
  def initialize(args = {})
    @contact = args[:contact]
    @contact_id = args[:contact_id]
    @employee = args[:employee]
    @employee_id = args[:employee_id]
  end

  def call
    return Log.both_filters(employee, contact).date_ordered      if employee? && contact?
    return Log.by_employee(employee_id || employee).date_ordered if employee_id.present? || employee?
    return Log.by_contact(contact_id   || contact).date_ordered  if contact_id.present?  || contact?

    Log.all.date_ordered
  end

  private

  attr_reader :contact, :employee

  def contact?
    contact.present?
  end

  def employee?
    employee.present?
  end
end
```